# Determining if a finite matrix group is irreducible in the Adjoint representation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, gap

Let $ G $ be a finite group of matrices. In particular suppose that $ G $ is a finite subgroup of $ SU_n $. What would be the best way to use GAP to figure out if the adjoint representation of $ G $ on $ \mathfrak{su}_n $ is irreducible?

One way to do this would be to use Schur's lemma. In other words, to show that $ G $ is Ad-irreducible it is enough to show that for $ Ad:G \to GL(\mathfrak{su}_n) $ the centralizer $ C_{GL(\mathfrak{su}_n)}(Ad(G)) $ is just multiplies of the identity.

Comment: OK somebody downvoted and somebody upvoted. Probably downvote wants me to add more details so I'll do that

Comment: Over which field(s)? What do you have from $G$ (generators?). Would it be plausible to construct matrices for the adjoint representation?

Comment: @ahulpke  $ SU_n $ is standard complex unitary group. The generators of $ G $ are all complex matrices ( entries from $ \mathbb{Q}(E(8),ER(5)) $ where $ E(8) $ is a primitive eight root of unity and $ ER(5) $ is the square root of $ 5 $). To construct matrices I need to take a basis for $ \mathfrak{su_n}=<M_1,\dots, M_{n^2-1}> $ then act generators $ g_i $ by conjugation and take coordinates of $ g_i^{-1}M_jg_i $ with respect to the $ \{M_j\} $ basis. I imagine this is plausible although I'm very new to Gap (downloaded yesterday). I can post the $ SU_4 $ matrices if that would be helpful?

Comment: Gershon Texeira (never know how to direct to IDs with blank in): You will need to construct matrices for the action on the adjoint module. I know that this is fiddly (and thus I'm not offering to do this myself from generators of $G$ :-(   )

Comment: @ahulpke Ya I thought it might be fiddly. Another approach would be character theory. $ G $ is Ad-irreducible if and only if $2= \sum_{g \in G} |tr(g)|^4= <\chi^2 ,\chi^2>$ where $ \chi=tr(Ad) $ for the rep of $ G $. Would doing that computation in GAP be easier/less fiddly?

Comment: If you can use the character of the natural representation rather than the adjoint rep., that certainly helps, though I don't recognize the formula you gave.

Comment: @ahulpke yes it is the (square) of the character of the natural representation. I just updated my question with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generically, the following should work to get your character formula evaluated (group is `G`)

```
Size(G);
Length(ConjugacyClasses(G));
```

For convenience, we define a small auxiliary function that evaluates, for a complex $t$, $|t|^4$. We use that `GaloisCyc(t,-1)` is the complex conjugate:

```
apow:=function(t)
  return (t*GaloisCyc(t,-1))^2;
end;
```

With this, we can now evaluate the trace sum over the conjugacy classes -- we sum over the conjugacy classes and weigh each term with the size of the class (you will still have to divide by the group order):

```
Sum(ConjugacyClasses(G),x->Size(x)*apow(TraceMat(Representative(x))));
```

Comment: Small stuff: the function apow you defined is actually $ (|t|^2)^4=|t|^8 $. Also, in my original question I forgot to divide by $ |G|  $ when taking the norm of the character ( I edited now and fixed it). So, (even after fixing apow to $ (|t|^2)^2=|t|^4 $) the code above doesn't actually given 2 for an Ad irreducible group but rather gives $ 2|G| $. Big stuff: thank you ahulpke this was exactly what I needed. It's only a few lines of code for you but to me this was so helpful. I'm sure you know how much the folks you help on MSE are grateful, but just wanted to reiterate: You are a rockstar!

Comment: Thank you for your kind words and for spotting the exponent eroor. Should be fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: In this case, ComplexConjugate(t) is the same as GaloisCyc(t,-1) right?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Yes

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find finite subgroups of $ SU(n) $ with this property then just search GAP for finite groups $ G $ with a degree $ n $ character $ \chi $ with
$$
\text{Norm}(\chi)=2
$$
this is very easy to do with the Norm command in GAP. TL;DR the easy way to do this is just search GAP for characters with norm 2.

Here are details of the character theory approach: Consider the natural module $ (SU_n, V=\mathbb{C}^n) $. Then $ V \otimes V^* \cong GL(V) $ decomposes as the $ n^2-1 $ irrep $ \mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C}) $ (which is the complexification of $ \mathfrak{su}_n $) together with a 1 dimensional trivial irrep (the span of the identity matrix $ \sum_{i=1}^n e_i \otimes e_i^* $). So for a finite subgroup $ G $ of $ SU_n $ then the adjoint representation is irreducible if and only if $ V \otimes V^* $ is the direct sum of exactly two irreducible $ G $ modules. In other words
$$
1+1=(\theta,\theta)
$$
where $ \theta $ is the character of $ (G,V \otimes V^*) $. But the trace of the tensor product is the product of the traces so $ \theta $ is just the square of $ \chi $, where $ \chi $ is the character of the natural representation $ (G,V) $. So in the end we have that $ G $ is $ Ad $ irreducible iff
$$
2=(\theta,\theta)=(\chi^2,\chi^2)=\frac{1}{|G|}
\sum_{g\in G} |tr(g)|^4
$$